# How to implement a UITextField similar to email Text Field in MFMailComposeController

Tags: ios, uitextfield, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In `MFMailComposeController`, once we start typing, the list of email addresses is shown. Once we select, the TextField displays the name of the user with a small Oval background. Then we can continue typing. If we want to delete it, then pressing backspace selects the oval background and on second backspace the email address is deleted. How can this be implemented.

I am not interested in the search part. I am fine with Implementing it. But I am more interested in getting the TextField working as in the MFMailComposeController. The way the blue oval background is set for already typed in emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to search through a set addresses,strings or whatever you can implement `UISearchDisplayController` and you will getyour job done.Here's the link on [UISearchDisplayController iPhone](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/).

Else , if you want to have youown you have will have to have a UITextField with a UITableView and you will have to implement the delegates method of UITextField to get the autocomplete feature searching through tableview's datasource.Implement your logic using delegates of UITableView and UITexField.

Comment: I am not interested in the search part. I am fine with Implementing it. But I am more interested in getting the TextField working as in the MFMailComposeController.

Answer (score 0):

you can use many open source implementation one name from them is [TITokenFieldView](https://github.com/enriquez/TITokenFieldView).